# Custom IoT Endpoint

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

We need to use a custom IoT endpoint due to firewall restrictions and needing to utilize Static Ips.  [We followed this AWS doc to get our endpoint with static Ips.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/creating-static-ip-addresses-and-custom-domains-for-aws-iot-core-endpoints/).  From here we are attempting to call the [CreateKeysAndCertificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/fleet-provision-api.html#create-keys-cert) via Java.  Now when we call IoT with our custom domain name, iot.custom.domain.name.com, with the regular Java SDK it works fine.  However, whenever we try to use the Android SDK and call `setEndpoint` with our custom domain we get the following error

```
com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found (Service: AWSIot; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException
```

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Android SDK for establishing IOT connections, the `CreateKeysAndCertificateRequest` API is available through the `AWSIotClient` class. If you are using the `AWSIotClient` for creating new certs/keys, the SDK places this request on the generic `iot.<region>.amazonaws.com` endpoint. The `setEndpoint` method just allows you to change the region. This is because the request goes to the Control plane, whereas the endpoint that you have created would mostly likely be on the Data plane. There is no way around to create new certs/keys using the `AWSIotClient` on the custom endpoint.

There is an alternate option that you can make use of. Almost all "requests" that you place on the IOT endpoint are messages that are published to ["reserved topics"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/reserved-topics.html). If you [open up the Java SDK's `PublishCreateKeysAndCertificate` API](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2/blob/main/sdk/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/iot/iotidentity/IotIdentityClient.java#L80), you will see that it is ultimately publishing a message over a reserved topic. You can do something similar on Android using the  Android SDK as well.

First, you will have to establish an authenticated connection. We cannot use `CognitoCredentialsProvider` because of that auth request going to the Control Plane. Instead, you can use the provisioning certificates for the first time authentication. This is through [provision certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-wo-cert.html) generated for a Provisioning Fleet. You can create a Provisioning Fleet and use those certificates in your device's keystore (or, a PKCS12 cert file). Using that, you can create a new `awsIotMqttManager` object and publish a message on the reserved topic meant for creating new certs/keys. You can also subscribe to reserved topics meant for receiving the "accepted"/"rejected" responses for this request.

TL;DR

- Create an `awsIotMqttManager` using the provision certs
- Subscribe to topic for listening for accepted/rejected response for `CreateKeysAndCertificates` request
- Publish a message over the reserved topic meant for `CreateKeysAndCertificates`
- Register the thing using the ownershipToken received in the response
- Store the new certs and use them for all future connections (make sure the policy attached to the certs have the necessary permissions)